# How to change subsequent row values when a condition is met in a row?

Tags: r, dataframe

Just wondering if anyone knows how to get R to change all future row values when a condition is met in a dataframe?

i.e. Say there is a negative value in column of data - I would like R to test the column for negative values and that value as well as values in subsequent rows 0 (regardless of whether the values following the negative value are negative or not).

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very elegant but works well using "classic" R. If x includes the numerical values:

```
f <- function(x) {
  quel <- which(x < 0)[1]
  if(is.na(quel)) return(x)
  x[quel:length(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
}
apply(x, 2, f)
```

Example:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100,-1,1), ncol=10))
print(x)
print(apply(x, 2, f))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative base R approach might be to use `cumsum`:

Consider the following data.frame:

```
data
   V1 V2
1   6 19
2  16  9
3  -1 14
4  18 11
5  19  2
6   1 18
7  11 -1
8  18  1
9  11  7
10  9 19
```

We can use cumsum to identify the values needing to be replaced with `0`:

```
sapply(data, function(x){cumsum(x <0) > 0})
        V1    V2
 [1,] FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE FALSE
 [6,]  TRUE FALSE
 [7,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [8,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [9,]  TRUE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

From there it is easy:

```
sapply(data, function(x){x[cumsum(x <0) > 0] <- 0; x})
      V1 V2
 [1,]  6 19
 [2,] 16  9
 [3,]  0 14
 [4,]  0 11
 [5,]  0  2
 [6,]  0 18
 [7,]  0  0
 [8,]  0  0
 [9,]  0  0
[10,]  0  0
```

Sample Data:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- as.data.frame(replicate(2,round(runif(0,20,n= 10),0)))
data[3,1] <- data[7,2] <- -1
```